# How to use gSheets vlookup for joining a few columns?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I saw this [post](http://chrome-extension://fiabciakcmgepblmdkmemdbbkilneeeh/park.html?title=How%20to%20VLOOKUP%20Multiple%20Criteria%20in%20Google%20Sheets%20(Easy%20Steps)%20-%20Spreadsheet%20Point&url=https%3A%2F%2Fspreadsheetpoint.com%2Fvlookup-multiple-criteria-google-sheets%2F&tabId=1110&sessionId=1614684467444&icon=data%3Aimage%2Fpng%3Bbase64%2CiVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAEAAAABACAYAAACqaXHeAAADsUlEQVR4Xu2bz2tcVRzFP%2BfOTDNpxJikTdrQxIZpSW2xtBWp4FYXbgouKujS0vxRQt0EXNiFUBQ3Bd2ISmmVYqsxjdSEhKY%2FMiaYZEzm3VNe0lSEIuRNsghzv5tZ3fPuO3O%2F937veeerkfGxCDTAdVCDlsJVUM8mxE7gbU1mp3Gf41U1Mj62IniCmbT8pKX3h24Iw0AFxceYRcQKZr0Qrqhg9iO6cTgAOU6cBhYL4T0bJKsPcdzQp5Hxy7OyJiBeiyr91hpwHDJ6SxsT9hzSjKXpDSKKhOiWPYw9hDRosyj8gxVmisBtjQnOTkC4YHk0XwFT4FsmXCl55VbDykrlrjwtth1lN49FeE%2FWQZsZE%2B8FxTtZ6Hi4bTCgFP%2Fpjw6nRDgmMWT5UYCvmyrfK4KXNZdDVS5l2n9OxEugc%2F8hYD2u3nBvdfWV1XqzyAMaaz2jhguYQzkBOE4Ewk%2FVzvqDQnirPYci8SwKozkBiAeCa9V99YkieH919pS10OishM43X0hADOHHlyqPl%2B9%2BcHWtyAOOfjZ2IkS9bztfrjNCvzbX12%2FOXPp0rgje0JWPB8uVyhvGr%2BUESJqLwV%2Fc%2F%2BiTQql68vOL%2B%2F5eP9AVYjyfCHhRCqQVkFIg7QFpE0ynQDoGUx2QCqFUCaZSON0F2ukydHkWuIO5qsDPuSwWQzEFJ2TUMO9EeQB4KIUph3gbNF%2FkNggeUAyn7VgD%2BoM1j7geS0wVwQuRCrjqyBnEReDUhiQGmrb9HcF%2FCmVChQQRovstTmJ6EQ3hRyZMSSwUmbBNr4g1o4OYKmJB5i5BhQQW42BcIupVSW%2BDh3MCIqaONlitF5nov2PUBe5HVBRZzhWcXBZrRRLbkMNQH9CBWbI8KdSqdnkYdBZ8%2BBkBWgMvQ%2F7bQshlTIekJcMfyPeBaUeWiqAq8DIwjBnMUyAXQ41vYhUSWLbmIHyEwHnMkU0Cdj5mjW4I%2F2IxpahiKRDcK1NDHM1XgqBuhW%2BI5MRuO%2BwsWJSCQg38Lqi2KwTY%2Bb%2FPdcT3zrLbselCm2Aoa0Cl0mnB8c2VoHmX4pfZaja57bfPtfpyuezQ7LQqZ0T8EOv1XSEA9DvEr3D4di9ogruQAomAtAJSCqQ9IG2C6RRIx2CqA1IhlCrBVArvAX9AugsUuVr%2B35h0HYY9Joi43SWxNhdF210WTx9GnjtFk0ssucSSSyy5xJJLLLnEkkssucSSSyy5xJJLrJBTJLXMpJ6hPd401fZtc23aOJlaZ9u9ebq92%2BefAqHcJ4rb2rZnAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) about using vlookup for joining two or more tables in google sheets.

However, I see it help joining just one column (see `$C$4:$C$12`). How would it work for a multiple columns?

```
VLOOKUP(B17&" "&C17,{$A$4:$A$12&" "&$B$4:$B$12,$C$4:$C$12}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `vlookup` in this case by specifying multiple column indexes. In this example, if there's an additional column D:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(B17&" "&C17,{$A$4:$A$12&" "&$B$4:$B$12,$C$4:$C$12,$D$4:$D$12},{2,3},false))
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]